# Concatenation disallowed on transformation CLM_DATA. Active transformation(RTR.T_GRP,RTR.B_GRP)

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am trying to link my Expression to Target table but i'm having the error message.Concatenation disallowed on transformation CLM_DATA. Active transformation(RTR.T_GRP,RTR.B_GRP)
[screenshot of my RTR and EXP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzub9.png)

Comment: Can you provide the screen shot of the error message as well?

Comment: Thanks Jim, I finally changed the mapping and not having that error message again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an Active transformation on parallel pipeline. Active transformation is one that may change the order or number of rows. In such case you can't bring both pipelines to one transformation - a joiner needs to be used.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's exactly what was the problem, I resolved the issue by using a joiner.

Comment: Great. Consider marking this as the correct answer for anyone having same issue in future.